# Решение задачи Яндекс контест оказалось неверным

Tags: javascript

Решал задачу в яндекс контесте, но после компиляции вылезла ошибка. Не понимаю что от меня требуется, ведь программа работает правильно

Условия задачи:

> Напишите функцию createCountdown, которая будет принимать не
> отрицательное целое число в качестве единственного аргумента и
> возвращать новую функцию без аргументов. Возвращаемая функция должна,
> с каждым своим вызовом, по одному, возвращать целые числа от
> изначально заданного до нуля. Все последующие вызовы, после вызова
> вернувшего ноль, должны так же возвращать ноль.
>
> Например:

```
const countdownFrom2 = createCountdown(2)
countdownFrom2() // 2 
countdownFrom2() // 1 
countdownFrom2() // 0
countdownFrom2() // 0
```

> Если единственный аргумент функции
> createCountdown не является не отрицательным целым числом, это нужно
> воспринимать как вызов с аргументом равным 0.
>
> Примечания Решение должно представлять из себя валидный JavaScript с
> определением функции createCountdown на верхнем уровне.

[image: Ошибка посылки]

Код, который я отправил:

```
function createCountdown(num){
    if (num<0){
      num = 0;
    }
  return ()=>{
    if (num !=0){
    num = num - 1;
    }
  };     
};
```

Comment: Замените ваши скрины на текст

Comment: Заменил скриншот на текст

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не возвращаете функцию, если аргумент отрицательный, а она должна быть и возвращать нули

```js
function createCountdown(num=0) {
  if (typeof num !== 'number') num = 0;
  return () => {
    if (num <= 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return num--
  }
};

cd2 = createCountdown(2)
console.log(cd2())
console.log(cd2())
console.log(cd2())
```

Comment: а что он делает если аргумент отрицательный?

Comment: Код не прошел третий тест

Comment: делает функцию, которая возвращает все время 0

Comment: @Егор там как - причин не пишут?

Comment: причин не пишут. Сухо прошел тест/не прошел

Comment: @splash58 Отредактированный вариант тоже не прошел третий тест

Comment: не понял чем "делает функцию, которая возвращает все время 0" отличается от "должна быть и возвращать нули"

Comment: @teran А вариант в вопросе? - ничего не возвращает

Comment: третий тест видимо про запуск без аргументов

Comment: @splash58 вариант в вопросе функцию то возвращает, это вот та функция там ничего не возвращает

Comment: @teran я не нашел в вопросе про без аргументов, но добавить легко

Comment: @splash58 все тот же третий тест не проходит

Comment: а да, пардон, это я криво прочитал про без аргументов

Comment: @Егор к сожалению, моих случайных знаний про яваскрипт не хватит, чтоб это победить :(

Comment: @Егор Добавьте проверку на входящий тип данных, там условиях задчи есть про это `typeof num !== 'number'`

Comment: @SwaD действительно, с такой проверкой все тесты пройдены. Благодарю за помощью всех соучастников

Answer (score 0):

```
function createCountdown(num) {
  return () => {
    if (typeof num !== 'number' || num <= 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return num--
  }
};
```